# XBee PRO S2 firmware

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I am new using the XBee PRO series 2. I accomplished to have communication between modules, but there is a thing that I don't understand at all.

My coordinator uses the firmware **ZNET 2.5 Coordinator API**.

The rest of the devices are using the **ZNET 2.5 Router/End Device API firmware**.

My question is how this last firmware works:

1. Is it a Router or is it an End Device?
   As far as I know, the Routers can not sleep, but can route messages through the network. Instead, the End Devices can sleep.
2. How can I switch between these two types of devices? Is there some parameter?
3. How does a coordinator know the existence of the End Devices that are not reachable via [RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency), but are between a Router?

I tried to register into DIGI forum to ask this questions, but I think they have some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Digi's documentation](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000866_G.pdf), the section "End Device sleep configuration" on Page 43:

> The sleep mode is settable using the SM command. If SM=0, sleep mode is disabled and the device operates as a router. If SM changes from 0 to a non-zero value, the router leaves the ZigBee network and attempts to rejoin as an end device. For this change to be successful, the end device must be able to join a nearby router or coordinator that is allowing end device joins.

I'd recommend reading the entire "Sleeping End Devices" section of that documentation to better understand how they work.

Regarding your question 3, the sleeping end device's parent (either a router or the coordinator) keeps a table of its child devices, and is responsible for answering on their behalf when another device on the network is performing node discovery.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was confusing about "how to change the type" I thought that there was to be something like this, because the Routers does not sleep.   Best Regards.